# JavaScript simple submit isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys i am having some problems with `javascript`, and i was wondering whether you could help me out?

This is my **`HTML`** code

```
<div class="Answer1"> 
    <form name="form">
        Enter your answer here :
        <input type="text" size="10" name="answer" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Check"  onclick="result();">
</form>
</div>

<!--2st sum -->
<div class="Answer2">
    <form name="form">
        Enter your answer here : 
        <input type="text" size="10" name="answer" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Check"  onclick="result2();">
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is my **`javascript`**

```
function result() {
    var  score = (document.form.answer.value);
    if(score == 8) {
        document.location.href="CorrectAdditionAnswer.html"
} else {
        document.location.href="IncorrectAddition.html"
    }
}

function result2() {
    var  score = (document.form.answer.value);
    if(score == 8) {
        document.location.href="CorrectAdditionAnswer2.html"
    } else {
        document.location.href="IncorrectAddition.html"
    }
}
```

If I comment out one of these it works perfectly fine but if its not commented it doesnt work :( I dont understand what ive done wrong :(

Comment: You can't redirect **and** submit a form

Comment: have you try with <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementById">getElementByID</a>

Comment: Also you have two times an input with `name="answer"`

Comment: You should be using `window.location` instead of `document.location`... [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.location)

Comment: I don't know what you're exactly trying to do, but I'm sure you're doing it wrong... first I would suggest to name your forms differently. I would also suggest using id's instead of names.

Comment: @Ian but he can submit and **then** redirect using ajax.

Comment: its more of a enter a answer if its correct it redirects you to one page if its incorrect it redirects you to another.. and sorry no i havent @Ligth

Comment: @WooCaSh You're right, but is that what their code's doing? No. They're trying to redirect when the form is submitted. Both can't happen. I'm sure a valid answer to this question would be to do what you're suggesting. I was just trying to point out why it wasn't working

Comment: it's mess... get IDs for forms and inputs try form.submit instead of redirecting.

Comment: I've sorted it all, it was to do with the names, sorry i havent got much experience in this:) thanks for your help all!

Comment: @Ian I write without offensive. I just suggest how to resolve this problem based on your comment ;)

Comment: @WooCaSh Oh I understand, no offense was taken. I was just pointing out the "problem", not trying to say it wasn't possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js

```
     function result()
{
    var  score =document.getElementsByName('answer1')[0].value;

    if(score == 8)
    {
      document.getElementsByName('form1')[0].action = "http://www.wordpress.com";
      document.getElementsByName('form1')[0].submit();
    }
    else
    {   
      document.getElementsByName('form1')[0].action = "http://www.bing.com";
      document.getElementsByName('form2')[0].submit();
    }
}

function result2()
{
    var  score = document.getElementsByName('answer2')[0].value;
    if(score == 8)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('form2')[0].action = "http://www.wordpress.com";
      document.getElementsByName('form2')[0].submit();
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementsByName('form2')[0].action = "http://www.bing.com";
      document.getElementsByName('form2')[0].submit();
    }
}
```

html

```
<div>  
<form name="form1">

        Enter your answer here :
        <input type="text" size="10" name="answer1" value="">

        <input type="button" value="Check"  onclick=" result();">
        </form>

</div>

<!--2st sum -->
<div class="Answer2">

        <form name="form2">
        Enter your answer here : 
        <input type="text" size="10" name="answer2" value="">

        <input type="button" value="Check"  onclick="  result2();">
        </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `form` with the same value for `name` attribute and two `input` with the same value for `name`.

Comment: thank you very much ive sorted everything out it was to do with diffrent form names, answers and the document.form.answer names, i had to give individual names its fully functioning now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To have same id for several elements put javascript in 'gridlock'.  Identify your element with an unique id name is usually faster and easier for DOM / Javascript / jQuery to find the node/element faster.

This format is appropriate method if all of elements are in the same page.

```
 <form name="form1">
    Enter your answer here :
    <input type="text" size="10" id="answer1" name="answer1" value="">

    <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="result1();">
    </form>

</div>

<!--2st sum -->
<div class="Answer2">

    <form name="form2">
    Enter your answer here : 
    <input type="text" size="10" id="answer2" name="answer2" value="">

    <input type="button" value="Check"  onclick="result2();">
    </form>
```